# Enable specific date in angular ui bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the datepicker from angular ui bootstrap and I need to apply 2 conditions, the first condition is that all days greater than today must be disable, this is easy, all I have to do is this:

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yyyy',
            maxDate: new Date(),
            startingDay: 1
        };
```

But the second condition is the next; I have two ENABLE the next weekend ignoring the first condition. How can I do this?

Comment: You could look into momentjs. It provides the functionality to get dates by day of week and then leverage that output to disable dates not in the list you generate with it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, so this is not posible in the datapicker from angular ui ??

Answer (score 0):

Go with basic java script as

```
 $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yyyy',
        maxDate: new Date("October 13, 2016 11:13:00"),
        startingDay: 1
    };
```

follow this link for requied date format

[Angular Js Date Formats](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)